# PHP: Undefined variable error on running search function

Tags: php, global-variables, undefined

My page has a search form which I am running from **index.php**, by calling a search function in **function.php** and with connection established with setup.php.

The search-field appears fine and there is not database connection error. The error that's popping up however is: `Notice: Undefined variable: search_results` in index.php (). The exact line is where it appears right below the form as: `<?php if ( $search_results ) : ?>`. I figured it was because **$search_results** was not declared as **global** in the first `if` statement. But after turning it global, the error still remains.

Would appreciate any insight into the reason for the error.

Here is a snapshot of the error:[image]

**Content of index.php**:

```
<?php require_once  ('setup.php');
require_once  ('function.php');    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
  global $search_results;
  $search_term = htmlspecialchars($_GET['s'], ENT_QUOTES);
  $search_results = search($conn, $search_term);     
  }
?>


<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="">
                <label>
                <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search" value="searchitem" name="s" 
                title="Search after:">
                </label>
                <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">              
</form>

  <?php if ( $search_results ) : ?>
    <div class="results-count">
      <p><?php echo $search_results['count']; ?> results found</p>
    </div>
    <div class="results-table">
      <?php foreach ( $search_results['results'] as $search_result ) : ?>
      <div class="result">
        <p><?php echo $search_result->title; ?></p>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="search-raw">
      <pre><?php print_r($search_results); ?></pre>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<body>
</html>
```

**Function.php**:

```
<?php

function search($conn, $search_term) {
    $sanitized = $conn->mysqli->real_escape_string($search_term);

    $query = $conn->mysqli->query("
      SELECT *
      FROM news
      WHERE title LIKE '%{$sanitized}%'
      OR body LIKE '%{$sanitized}%'
      OR sources LIKE '%{$sanitized}%'
      OR date LIKE '%{$sanitized}%'
    ");


    if ( ! $query->num_rows ) {
      return false;
    }


    while( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
      $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $search_results = array(
      'count' => $query->num_rows,
      'results' => $rows,
    );

    return $search_results;
  }
 ?>
```

**Setup.php:**

```
<?php
$hn = 'localhost';
$db = 'boh';
$un = 'water';
$pw = 'water'; 

#DB Connection:
 $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
 if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
?>
```

---

**As suggested in the reply**, I tried `if ( isset($search_results ))`, and this got rid of the error, but when I ran the search (clicked on the button), got the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined property: mysqli::$mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\function.php on line 4

Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\function.php on line 4
```

**Line 4** : $sanitized = $conn->mysqli->real_escape_string($search_term);

Comment: Try `if ( isset($search_results )) ` - at the moment, you're checking to see if the variable is truthy, not if it exists. You can also get around this by declaring `$search_results = ''` at the start of your code.

Comment: When I give if ( isset($search_results )), there is no error, but running the search (clicking the search button) gives 2 more errors. Updating in answer.

Comment: Try ` $conn->real_escape_string($search_term)` instead. Though I'd advise you don't escape the data, but use bound parameters instead.

Comment: Same 2 errors. What does this error refer to: `Notice: Undefined property: mysqli::$mysqli `?

Comment: You've not changed the right piece of code. The error means that there's no `$mysqli` property as part of your `$conn` object, and since there wasn't a reference to `mysqli` in the change I suggested, I'm not sure where it's coming from.

Comment: I think these errors were pre-exisitng, just that I could not see it before I changed to: `if ( isset($search_results ))`

Comment: You'll also want to remove the `mysqli->` from where you call `query`, in your search function.

Comment: @andewsi - that was it! works - thanks - can't upvote you in the comments though :(   Will update with a mention in the question then.

Comment: Well, it was just a typo; you might want to delete this question.